# Google Sites embed code how to remove unnecessary padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sites

I have this element embedded in my Google Site.  For the progress bar to be visible properly on the mobile site, I need to drag the container box to a huge size, scroll bars appear while viewing from a mobile device. But then it has huge white gaps on the desktop app.

```js
function updateProgressBar(raisedAmount) {
  const goalAmount = 50000;
  const percentage = (raisedAmount / goalAmount) * 100;
  const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
  progressBar.style.width = percentage + "%";
  const raisedAmountElement = document.querySelector(".raised-amount");
  raisedAmountElement.textContent = "₹" + raisedAmount.toLocaleString("en-IN");
}
const initialRaisedAmount = 7698;
updateProgressBar(initialRaisedAmount);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,500');
.progress-bar {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #fdc700, #ffde66);
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.donation-info {
  height: 80px;
  /* Reduced height */
  padding: 0px;
  /* Adjusted padding */
  font: 500 20px/1 'Open Sans';
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.goal-amount {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .goal-amount {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .raised-info {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.progress-bar-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #dee0e0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}

.update-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  /* Apply Open Sans font-family */
}

.raised-info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  /* Removed padding */
  float: left;
}

.raised-amount,
.raised-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.raised-amount {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.goal-words {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Donation Progress Bar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="donation-info">
    <div class="raised-info">
      <span class="raised-label">RAISED</span>
      <span class="raised-amount" id="raised-amount">₹5000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="goal-words">GOAL</div>
    <div class="goal-amount">₹50,000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="update-text">This number is updated every 24hrs</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried tinkering around the padding and container heights, but I have no idea how to fix it. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Could you show an example, please?